# How do I bind template with style?

Tags: c#, wpf, templates, xaml, styles

I have a C# WPF application where I need to create a bunch of image/text buttons with different colors.  To that end I created an ImageButton derived from Button class.

I want my button to have round corners so I have created the following control template:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="RoundedButtonTemplate" 
  TargetType="{x:Type MyProject:ImageButton}">
  <Grid>
    <Border x:Name="border" 
      Background="WHAT DO I PUT HERE?" CornerRadius="10"/>
  </Grid>
```

Now I want to be easily able to change the color of the border above, just by changing styles in XAML.  I have the following styles defined.

Green Button Style:

```
<Style x:Key="GreenButtonStyle" 
  TargetType="{x:Type MyProject:ImageButton}">
  <Setter Property="Background" 
          Value="{DynamicResource GreenButtonBrush}"/>
          RoundedButtonTemplate}"/>
  </Style>
```

Blue Button Style:

```
<Style x:Key="GreenButtonStyle" 
  TargetType="{x:Type MyProject:ImageButton}">
  <Setter Property="Background" 
          Value="{DynamicResource BlueButtonBrush}"/>
          RoundedButtonTemplate}"/>
</Style>
```

My client code looks like this:

```
<local:ImageButton HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
    Margin="24,19.234,0,20" Width="97" 
    Grid.Row="3" 
    Style="{DynamicResource GreenButtonStyle}" 
    Template="{DynamicResource RoundedButtonTemplate}"/>
```

My question is how do I make the template know which style to use?  I tried adding the following property to my style, but didn't have much success:

```
<Setter Property="Template" 
    Value="{DynamicResource RoundedButtonTemplate}"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out.  All that was needed was placing the following text in my template definition:

```
Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
```

More information can be found in this article:
[TemplateBinding: a bridge between styles and templates](http://devlicio.us/blogs/christopher_bennage/archive/2008/07/04/templatebinding-a-bridge-between-styles-and-templates.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that ImageButton inherits from UserControl since this is a composite control.  If not, you probably should.  MSDN discusses inheriting from Control vs UserControl.  I would put the Border in there, and inside a Button and a TextBlock or something.

One way to do this would be to define a Dependency Property on your new ImageButton class, something like "BorderBackground."  You link this up to change the Border's Background color when you set it.  I can provide sample code if you like.

When you set your styles, the target property would be "BorderBackground."  This would eliminate the needs for any change to the ControlTemplate, which I generally try to avoid.

Does this help at all?

Or answer your original question, I am not sure if the Template would know how to have the style applied since your style targets the Background of the ImageButton control, not the Background of the Border control.